# Azure kubernetes - register services in Azure API management?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, swagger, azure-api-management, azure-aks

I am planning to deploy multiple applications on Azure kubernetes and each application will have multiple services.

I will have Azure API management in front of the kubernetes services.

As each application will have multiple services, how do I register those services in Azure API management? Would it be one by one? Is there a way to generate swagger document for the kubernetes services and register at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to register them as a different services, yes you need to do one by one. But there is a way You can create a single API in API Management that points to multiple different backend APIs. Use the [set-backend-service policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-and-publish) to change the backend API for certain operations.

Comment: Let's say, I have the Asp.net core web api application for a library with 3 actions. 1. GetSearchResults, 2.PostCheckIn & 3.PostCheckOut.  Now, the application is deployed and exposed as a single service say http://10.10.0.5. Now, if I want to configure API management for this service and added an API that points http://10.10.0.5. How many operations I have to configure, 3?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar yes 3. You could export OpenAPI/Swagger from your ASP.NET Core, import it to APIM to have all these operations and then use APIM policy set-backend-service to route to the 1 backend/service your K8S hosted service.